# Trouble using <f:ajax> on JSF 2.0

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I posted a question here last week about using Ajax with J2EE and got and answer about the build in support of ajax with JSF 2.0. Unfortunately I just cant seem to get any example of this to work!

I have tried out using different IDEs with different servers but I cant get this basic example to work.

A session scoped managed bean:

```
public class testBean 
{
    private String name;

    public testBean() {}


    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And the xhtml page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<head>
  <title>Default title</title>
</head>

    <body>

        <h:form id="testForm"> 

            <h:inputText id="test" value="#{testBean.name}" > 
                <f:ajax event="keyup" render="testForm:name" execute="testForm:test"/> 
            </h:inputText> 


            <h:outputText id="name" value="#{testBean.name}" /> 
        </h:form>   

    </body>

</html>
```

From my knowledge the page should display the text that is written while it is being written right next to the inputText form, but that is not happening.

I hate making two topics about roughly the same thing but I really dont know whats wrong here, from what Ive read this code should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong event specified in your `f:ajax`. Use `keyup` or `keypress` instead of `click`:

```
<h:inputText id="test" value="#{testBean.name}" > 
  <f:ajax event="keyup" render="name" execute="test"/> 
</h:inputText>
```

the onclick / click event handler is only fired by a mouse click.

**UPDATE:**

Didn't notice it before:

I think you should use `<h:head>` instead of `<head>` to include all javascript resources for ajax correctly.

Comment: Its a typo, I was testing around with different events. The keyup was the tested value and it does not work.